# getting new radio and checkbox values within function when changed

Tags: jquery

I have a `function` called filter which basically gets the value of 2 radio inputs and 1 check box. I have setup the function to be triggered on either a `change` event.

Issue I am having is the value for any 3 of those does not change when the function fires.

Why is the value not changing? I must be missing something.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/r3rjavqu/4/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="filter_options">
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="pindexed" id="pindexed" class="pindexed" value="No" checked>
    Yes 
  </label>
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="pindexed" id="pindexed" class="pindexed" value="Yes">
    No 
  </label>
  <br />
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="dindexed" id="dindexed" class="dindexed" value="No" checked>
    Yes 
  </label>
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="dindexed" id="dindexed" class="dindexed" value="Yes">
    No 
  </label>

</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
function filter() {
    var pindexed = $("input:radio[name='pindexed']").val();
    var dindexed = $("input:radio[name='dindexed']").val();
    var removed_checked = $("input[type='checkbox']").val();
    alert(pindexed);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "gen_this.php",
        data: ({
            pindexed: pindexed,
            dindexed: dindexed,
            removed_checked: removed_checked
        }),
        success: function(data) {
            $('.gen_disavow_results').html(data);
        }
    });
};
$(document).on('change click', '#filter_options', function() {
    filter();
});
```

Comment: I do not see the symbol "dindexed" anywhere in the markup.  Typo?

Comment: oops edited sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you're getting the value of the element that's checked. An example would be to change to these three lines:

```
 var pindexed = $("input:radio[name='pindexed']:checked").val();
 var dindexed = $("input:radio[name='dindexed']:checked").val();
 var removed_checked = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the logic error is in the script, where you are asking for the value of input[name=petc], you aren't asking for the value of the selected one, but just for the value of the first one returned.

If you ask specifically for the value of the checked option, you get the actual value:

```
var pindexed = $("input:radio[name='pindexed']:checked").val();
```

However, I believe the change event fires BEFORE the change takes place, so if you click NO, to switch it from yes to no, the value is YES, because that was the value when you clicked it.

Comment: Nope. Look at his code, the values are actually just switched